# Как выровнять input и label?

Tags: css, веб-программирование, input, label, выравнивание

Не получается выровнять input и label.
Подскажите, пожалуйста: в чем может быть проблема?

```
<input id="radio" type="radio" name="remember" value="remember"/>
<label for="radio">ATCERĒTIES MANI</label>
```

```
#radio {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

#radio + label {
    background-color: white;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #210038;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 15%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#radio:checked + label {
    background-color: #210038;
    border: 1px solid #210038;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 13%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}

#remember_container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3px; 
    margin: 7px; 
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для стилизации `input` лучше использовать `:before`

```css
#radio {
    display: none;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
#radio + label{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#radio + label::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: white;
    width: 19px;
    height: 19px;
    border: 1px solid #210038;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 15%;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#radio:checked + label::before {
    content: "";
    background-color: #210038;
    border: 1px solid #210038;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: 13%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 1s;
}

#remember_container {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 3px; 
    margin: 7px; 
    padding: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<input id="radio" type="radio" name="remember" value="remember"/>
<label for="radio">ATCERĒTIES MANI</label>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё идеально работает)